# C++ void_t SFINAE false_type true_type can't get specialization

Tags: c++, templates, sfinae, void-t

It all seemed simple.

Shouldn't has_member_type::value be true for T=vector in my code below?  Sorry if it had already be answered.  I looked for a while, but couldn't find an answer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

// has_value_type
template <typename, typename = std::void_t<>>
struct  has_value_type: std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct has_value_type<T, std::void_t<typename T::value_type>>: std::true_type {};

int main()
{
    std::cout << "bool: " << std::boolalpha << has_value_type<bool>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "vector_has: " << std::boolalpha << has_value_type<std::vector<int>>::value << std::endl;

    std::cout << "true_type: " << std::boolalpha << std::true_type::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "false_type: " << std::boolalpha << std::false_type::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
bool: false
vector_has: false
true_type: true
false_type: false
```

I'm using clang++

```
clang version 9.0.0 (tags/RELEASE_900/final)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin17.7.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: Your example doesn't `#include <vector>` - If that is indeed what reproduces the error on your end, then that would be the culprit. Perhaps there is only a forward declaration introduced by another header. And so, the trait is querying an incomplete type. Meaning it *doesn't* have any members.

Answer (score 6):

If you use the `libc++` standard library implementation, and don't include `<vector>`, then a forward declaration of `std::vector` is introduced with:

```
#include <iostream> // forward declares std::vector
```

[demo](https://godbolt.org/z/5TrG87)

This forward declaration allows the code to compile, but the sfinae check returns `false` since there are no member types defined for `std::vector` yet.

You can't rely on this, and should always `#include<vector>` if you want to use `std::vector` in any context.